# SAP HANA Python Connection HDBCLI

Tags: python, sql, hana, python-db-api

After successfully installing the HDBCLI driver and connecting SAP HANA with Python, I created the below code to test the connection, however, I got an error:

`Error: (-10719, "Connect failed (invalid SERVERNODE ':30015')")`.

Does anyone know where can be the issue?

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
connection = dbapi.connect(
    host="gf_____lds",
    port=30015,
    user="______",
    password="_______"
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'Hello Python World' FROM DUMMY")
cursor.fetchone()
(u"Hello Python World",)

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the host parameter should be set in ”address” instead of “host” or as the first parameter in the function (with no name)

Answer (score 2):

I also found this issue. Below code copied from SAP document, in the example it was "address" but in use method it was "host". Change host to address fixed the issue.

Procedure

```
#Install the Python driver.
#Import the dbapi module:
from hdbcli import dbapi
#Use the connect method:
dbapi.connect(host='localhost', port=30015, user='system', password='manager')
```

**Example**

The following example Python code shows a database connection:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address="<hostname>", 
    port=3<NN>MM, 
    user="<username>", 
    password="<password>"
)
```

- For HANA tenant databases, you can use the port number 3<**NN**>13 (where <NN> is the SAP instance number).
- For HANA system databases in a multitenant system, the port number is 3**NN**13.
- For HANA single-tenant databases, the port number is 3**NN**15.